# Trying to package an Unreal project for Windows but it builds the default demo fps map?

Tags: unreal, build-process, unreal-5, platform

This is really frustrating but I made a complicated Unreal Engine level and it built the default FPS project. It didn't build a single asset in my scene.
[image]

I would build the project by clicking `Package Project`. (Btw the app isn't blank, I have the view turned away from the assets for IP protection purposes):
[image]

Also I have my project settings following the tutorials that I found online:
[image]
[image]

So why is it not building my game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I incorrectly put “Stage” as the "Editor Startup Map" instead of as the "Game Default Map."
[image]

So I switched the "Game Default Map" from "FirstPersonMap" to “Stage” and it built the correct scene.
[image]